# How to prevent creating(programmatically) item without setting values in required fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssom

I have list event receiver which creates item in another list.

Code:

```
newItem[fieldName1] = cellItem1;
newItem[fieldName2] = cellItem2;
newItem.Update();
```

The problem is that if any required field is not specified by me, the element will be saved.
For example: if the "Title" field is required, but I don't specify newItem["Title"] = cellItem1 - it will still be saved.

I need to prevent this - If a list has required fields and I do not specify their values - Item should **not** be created.

Yes I can get all list fields and create additional check - If (list.fields[field].Required)..... but may be there are other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research I can write that there are no OOTB settings to achieve this.

So the simpliest solution is to add the following check:

```
foreach (SPField f in properties.ListItem.Fields)
{
   if (!f.ReadOnlyField && f.Required && properties.AfterProperties[f.InternalName] == null)
    {
      //cancel adding item
    }
}
```